# Element is removed from document, but jest still finds it

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have built a wrapper around react-toastify, so that I can call it at multiple places.

Here is the code for wrapper:

```
import { ReactText } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

export const showNotification: (
  message: string,
  type?: 'info' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'error',
  timeOut?: number,
) => ReactText
  = (message, type = 'success', timeOut = 5000) => toast(
      message, { type, autoClose: timeOut },
    );

export const dismissNotification = (toastId: ReactText) => toast.dismiss(toastId);
```

Now, I am testing my dismissNotification function.

I have written this test case:

```
it('dismisses notification when called', async () => {
  render(<ToastContainer />);
  const notificationId = showNotification('Test Notification', 'success', 2000);
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText('Test Notification')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  dismissNotification(notificationId);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => {
    expect(screen.queryByText('Test Notification')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

But last test case always fails saying that a dom node with text `Test Notification` is present.

Actual Error:

```
dismisses notification when called

    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    expected document not to contain element, found <div class="Toastify__toast-body" role="alert">Test Notification</div> instead
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using `waitForElementToBeRemoved` incorrectly. According to [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitforelementtoberemoved), "the first argument must be an element, array of elements, or a callback which returns an element or array of elements."

In addition, it looks like you are facing some issue with the timeout. It seems the animation is causing the element to remain in the DOM for longer than you expect. You can perform two quick tests to confirm this is an issue.

First, inspect the DOM in your browser. When you dismiss the notification, you can see that the element is not removed right away.

Second, try setting a [custom transition](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/custom-transition) so we can play around with the duration. When you set the `collapseDuration` to something like `5000`, the toast takes a long time to disappear, and the test fails. When you set the `collapseDuration` to `0`, the toast disappears immediately, and the test passes.

```js
const Zoom = cssTransition({
  enter: 'zoomIn',
  exit: 'zoomOut',
  collapseDuration: 0,
  //duration: 5000,
});

toast(message, {
  type,
  autoClose: timeOut,
  transition: Zoom,
});
```

So I think you need to both fix how you are using `waitForElementToBeRemoved` and also apply a custom `timeout`. Try this code:

```js
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.queryByText('Test Notification'), { timeout: 5000 });
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question. If you can see line before `await waitForElementToBeRemoved ...`, I have a call to dismissNotification. So, before 1000ms, my notification will disappear.

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have missed that. I still think my code will work for you. Just remove the options object with `timeout`. I will edit to do that now.

Comment: I still think `timeout` is a problem, because the element is not removed until the animation completes. See more information in my edited post above.

Comment: Yeah I got it working. You are correct, timeout was the issue. Once I bumped up timeout to 2000 seconds, the test was passing. Then I bumped up the timeout of showNotification method just to be sure that notification is dismissed by dismissNotification function call and not due to timeout. So, the conclusion is: Notification was taking more than 1 seconds to complete its closing animation.